# Android で背景画像を水平方向のみに繰り返す方法

Tags: android, bitmap

Android の画像リソースを繰り返し表示する場合

```
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/back" 
    android:tileMode="repeat" />
```

このように XML で定義し、 View などに [`BitmapDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html) として設定します。

ところが、この方法だと水平および垂直の両方向に繰り返し表示されてしまいます。

水平方向のみに繰り返しを行い、垂直方向は繰り返ししないようにするには、どのようにすればよいでしょうか？

Answer (score 4):

```
BitmapDrawable draw = (BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.draw);
draw.setTileModeX(Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11934845/android-tilemode-x-or-y-only
より抜粋。

追記:
遥かに簡単な方法があった。

```
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/back" 
    android:tileModeX="repeat" />
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]